# intersection of two non rectangular objects?

Tags: java

if i have 2 JLabels and each of them has an ImageIcon set to it.
the icons are constructed from images read from the project folder, these images bounds are not rectangular and not circular or a uniform shape, they are bounds of cars.

i used a code to check the intersection of the labels using the absolute difference between their top left x coordinates and the absolute difference between their top left y coordinates, and comparing these differences with their width and height, but with this i am treating them as rectangles so intersection detection is not so accurate.

is there a way to detect the intersection based on the actual coordinates contained in each image ?
note that this check will be in a timer (it will be executed many times) so it is required to be not slow.

the code portion for initializing and settingJLables:

```
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel();
lbl1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("car1.png"));
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel();
lbl2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("car2.png"));
```

Comment: `JLabel` is supposed to be a GUI element. It sounds like you are making something like a game. I wouldn't go down this route. Find a good 2D game / physics engine and use that.

Comment: Absent any tools to help you with this, I would provide one or more collision hulls to a new `Car` class that holds the image to be drawn and its bounding shape(s). That way you can check for collisions between light-weight, simple, shapes instead of the image itself. Still, there are tradeoffs to be made between very accurate collision detection and the effort to achieve it. I also would not use a JLabel and ImageIcon to do it.